# Table rows become inline if rowspan is set for all the cells of the row

Tags: html, html-table

Here is what I need to do.

I'm creating a grid with widgets that are supposed to be represented in a table. Each widget has a variable width that represents the colspan of the td that contains it, and a height of 1 or 2 that is supposed to represent the rowspan of that cells.

Everything works fine, until I'm having a case where all the cells of a row have a colspan of 2, and the next row can have any type of cells. The next row is getting displayed right next to the previous row instead of the next one.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjPMw/2/) that replicates the problem and here is the code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan = "2">ONE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan = "1">1</td>
    <td rowspan = "1">2</td>
    <td rowspan = "1">3</td>
    <td rowspan = "1">4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: To be clear, what I want to do, is having a row of widgets that have twice the height of a regular row

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vjPMw/3/ is this what you mean?

Comment: in order for your table cell to span two rows, you need to have more than one row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to visualize exactly what you want, but perhaps you should be using block elements rather than a table. A table should only be used for tabular data. The `rowspan` attribute won't function correctly if there aren't any rows to span.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">ONE</td>
   <td>TWO</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2fee/)

Comment: Actually that prodded me to the correct direction. I fixed the issue by adding an empty row after every row with data, and now the table gets displayed the way it should :)

PS: I'm aware that block elements are better, but the current use case forced me to use a table... Oh well!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing a thing to two rows, which is normally only done when you have more cells in that set of rows, simply set the cell's height:

http://jsfiddle.net/vjPMw/5/

```
td {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
td.doubleheight {
    height: 40px;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="doubleheight">ONE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan = "1">1</td>
        <td rowspan = "1">2</td>
        <td rowspan = "1">3</td>
        <td rowspan = "1">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Really, I'd have expected even that to be unnecessary, as a cell normally expands to contain its contents. Maybe a more complete demo of your situation is in order. Also, I agree with Aarolama Bluenk that maybe a table isn't the right approach here to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The first row has 1 cell with rowspan=2, so html expects next row to be the one which is "spanned", however you've added row with 4 td's.
I'd recommend adding empty `<tr></tr>` after first one and play with it OR fix first td to: `<td rowspan="2" colspan="4">ONE</td>`